# How to add table row and colums at specific index

Tags: javascript, html

How to add a table row or table column at specific index by on clicking the table cells, same as excel sheet.

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th> 
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Add Row Script:

```
function AppendRows() {
        var tableRows = document.getElementById('myTable'),
            row = tableRows.insertRow(tableRows.rows.length);
        row.height = '50';
        for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
            row.insertCell(i), i, 'row';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how you can insert a new row. There are several approaches you can go with but basically this is the way

```js
function insertrow() {
  var newRowIndex = 1;
  var row1 = document.getElementById("table").childNodes[1].childNodes[newRowIndex];
  var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
  var col0 = document.createElement("td");
  col0.innerHTML = "newA";
  newRow.appendChild(col0);
  var col1 = document.createElement("td");
  col1.innerHTML = "newB";
  newRow.appendChild(col1);
  var col2 = document.createElement("td");
  col2.innerHTML = "newC";
  newRow.appendChild(col2);
  row1.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow, row1);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="insertrow()">Insert row</button>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also i'd suggest you take a look at the [insertBefore](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-952280727) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to insert a row after a row is clicked. The new row is added immediately after the clicked row, so new rows can be added at different locations.

Let's walk through it:

First we setup an event listener on the table to listen for clicks on the row elements. When a row is clicked, we call the the `appendRow` method to add a new row, and pass the index where we want the row to appear.

We're using delegation here so dynamically added rows will be included in the event listener.

The `appendRow` method adds a new row at the defined index, then adds a few table cells for presentation purposes.

```js
var tableEl = document.getElementById('table');
tableEl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var el = event.target;
  if (el.closest('tr') && el.closest('tbody')) {
    var trow = el.parentElement;
    var tbody = trow.parentElement;
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(tbody.children, trow);
    appendRow(tbody, index + 1);
  }
});

function appendRow(tbody, index) {
  var row = tbody.insertRow(index);
  var cells = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  cells.forEach(function(cell, idx) {
    var newCell = row.insertCell(idx);
    var newText = document.createTextNode(`Row ${index} - ${cell}`);
    newCell.appendChild(newText);
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```